# Why do instance variables seemingly disappear when inside a block?

Tags: ruby, block, instance-variables, savon

Forgive me, guys. I am at *best* a novice when it comes to Ruby. I'm just curious to know the explanation for what seems like pretty odd behavior to me.

I'm using the [Savon](http://savonrb.com/) library to interact with a SOAP service in my Ruby app. What I noticed is that the following code (in a class I've written to handle this interaction) seems to pass **empty values** where I expect the values of member fields to go:

```
create_session_response = client.request "createSession" do
  soap.body = {
    :user => @user, # This ends up being empty in the SOAP request,
    :pass => @pass  # as does this.
  }
end
```

This is despite the fact that both `@user` and `@pass` have been initialized as non-empty strings.

When I change the code to use locals instead, it works the way I expect:

```
user = @user
pass = @pass

create_session_response = client.request "createSession" do
  soap.body = {
    :user => user, # Now this has the value I expect in the SOAP request,
    :pass => pass  # and this does too.
  }
end
```

I'm guessing this strange (to me) behavior must have something to do with the fact that I'm inside a block; but really, I have no clue. Could someone enlighten me on this one?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

First off, `@user` is not a "private variable" in Ruby; it is an *[instance variable](http://phrogz.net/ProgrammingRuby/tut_classes.html#classesobjectsandvariables)*. Instance variables are available within the the scope of the current object (what `self` refers to). I have edited the title of your question to more accurately reflect your question.

A block is like a function, a set of code to be executed at a later date. Often that block will be executed in the scope *where the block was defined*, but it is also possible to evaluate the block in another context:

```
class Foo
  def initialize( bar )
    # Save the value as an instance variable
    @bar = bar
  end
  def unchanged1
    yield if block_given? # call the block with its original scope
  end
  def unchanged2( &block )
    block.call            # another way to do it
  end
  def changeself( &block )
    # run the block in the scope of self
    self.instance_eval &block
  end
end

@bar = 17
f = Foo.new( 42 )
f.unchanged1{ p @bar } #=> 17
f.unchanged2{ p @bar } #=> 17
f.changeself{ p @bar } #=> 42
```

So either you are defining the block outside the scope where `@user` is set, or else the implementation of `client.request` causes the block to be evaluated in another scope later on. You could find out by writing:

```
client.request("createSession"){ p [self.class,self] }
```

to gain some insight into what sort of object is the current `self` in your block.

The reason they "disappear" in your case—instead of throwing an error—is that Ruby permissively allows you to ask for the value of any instance variable, even if the value has never been set for the current object. If the variable has never been set, you'll just get back `nil` (and a warning, if you have them enabled):

```
$ ruby -e "p @foo"
nil

$ ruby -we "p @foo"
-e:1: warning: instance variable @foo not initialized
nil
```

As you found, blocks are also *[closures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_science))*. This means that when they run they have access to local variables defined in the same scope as the block is defined. This is why your second set of code worked as desired. Closures are one excellent way to latch onto a value for use later on, for example in a callback.

Continuing the code example above, you can see that the local variable is available regardless of the scope in which the block is evaluated, and takes precedence over same-named methods in that scope (unless you provide an explicit receiver):

```
class Foo
  def x
    123
  end
end
x = 99 
f.changeself{ p x } #=> 99
f.unchanged1{ p x } #=> 99
f.changeself{ p self.x } #=> 123
f.unchanged1{ p self.x } #=> Error: undefined method `x' for main:Object
```

Comment: Thanks! I was having great difficulty duplicating this with my own code blocks; seeing your example using `instance_eval` helped clear it up for me.

Comment: @Dan You're welcome. I've added a bit more to the end of the example showing closures in action for the simple case.

Comment: is there a pretty solution to this? Otherwise my N.times {} blocks can't access instance variables and work-around with o=self now become a syntactic mess :(

Comment: @Konrads A pretty solution to what? Ask a new question with your code, needs, and desires. A random comment with a snippet of code on an answer to someone else's question is not going to get you good help.

Answer (score 5):

From [the documentation](http://savonrb.com/version2/client.html):

> Savon::Client.new accepts a block inside which you can access local variables and even public methods from your own class, but instance variables won’t work. If you want to know why that is, I’d recommend reading about instance_eval with delegation.

Possibly not as well documented when this question was asked.

Answer (score 2):

In the first case, `self` evaluates to `client.request('createSession')`, which doesn't have these instance variables.

In the second, the variables are brought into the block as part of the closure.

Answer (score 2):

Another way to fix the issue would be to carry a reference to your object into the block rather than enumerating each needed attribute more than once:

```
o = self
create_session_response = client.request "createSession" do
  soap.body = {
    :user => o.user,
    :pass => o.pass
  }
end
```

But now you need attribute accessors.